# Bukkit create NPC with AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bukkit

I'm just looking for a way to spawn an NPC with an AI that just goes somewhere and doesn't do anything.
Does anyone know how to make something like this?

Comment: Is Citizens (and citizens API) what you're looking for?  https://github.com/CitizensDev/Citizens2

Comment: I wached a few videos about Citizens, but I have noticed that Citizens hasn't got a AI...
or not one that just randomly goes anywhere

Comment: Using the API, you can make it pathfind to a certain location, meaning you can just select randomly locations and pathfind to them

Comment: Yeah, something like this!

Comment: it just has to look like these are people going somewhere to make the city "alive".

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through the use of [Citizens2](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/citizens.13811/), a free NPC API built for Minecraft 1.8-1.19.

First, create the NPC:

```
NPC npc = CitizensAPI.getNPCRegistry().createNPC(EntityType.PLAYER, "CustomPlayer");  // "CustomPlayer" is the NPC's name
```

Next, give the NPC a `WanderGoal` to give them the wandering functionality you are looking for:

```
npc.getDefaultGoalController().addGoal(WanderGoal.createWithNPC(npc), 1);
```

Finally, spawn the NPC:

```
npc.spawn(location);`
```